# How do I create a parameter list for a function?

Tags: php

I am creating an array of arrays in the following way:

```
$final_array = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($elements); $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < count($elements); $j++) {
        if($i!=$j)
            $final_array[] = array_intersect($elements[$i], $elements[$j]);
    }
}
```

I am trying to find out the list of elements that occur in all the arrays inside the `$final_array` variable. So I was wondering how to pass this to `array_intersect` function. Can someone tell me how to construct args using `$final_array[0], $final_array[1], ... $final_array[end_value]` for `array_intersect`? Or if there is a better approach for this, that would be great too.

I am looking for a way to construct the following:

`array_intersect($final_array[0], $final_array[1], $final_array[2], ...)`

Comment: Excuse me if I did not understand your question but have you read this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php?

Comment: @G. Qyy: Actually I did :) I edited my question to provide what exactly I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need to do all of this work? Just use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array).

Comment: This look wonderful! Thanks a lot... I was not even aware of this function nor the existence of lambda functions in PHP though my version complains with a syntax error when I try to declare a custom function.

Comment: @Legend: `call_user_func_array` takes in a `callback`, which can be many different things (lambda, array, string). Have a look at the `callback` pseudotype: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback

Comment: Yeap.. Looking at it now... Thanks a lot.