# Calling a function with variable number of parameters?

Tags: php

In regard to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103729/how-do-i-create-a-parameter-list-for-a-function), [Jacob Relkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/220819/jacob-relkin) suggested a great solution of using [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/call_user_func_array). That solved my problem but now I am really curious on how to do this in the absence of this function to achieve what I wanted in my original question which is below for reference:

**[Original Question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103729/how-do-i-create-a-parameter-list-for-a-function)**

I am creating an array of arrays in the following way:

```
$final_array = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($elements); $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < count($elements); $j++) {
        if($i!=$j)
            $final_array[] = array_intersect($elements[$i], $elements[$j]);
    }
}
```

I am trying to find out the list of elements that occur in all the arrays inside the `$final_array` variable. So I was wondering how to pass this to `array_intersect` function. Can someone tell me how to construct args using `$final_array[0], $final_array[1], ... $final_array[end_value]` for `array_intersect`? Or if there is a better approach for this, that would be great too.

I am looking for a way to construct the following:

`array_intersect($final_array[0], $final_array[1], $final_array[2], ...)`

Comment: Why not `call_user_func_array`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the only real way to do this other than `call_user_func_array` would be to `implode` the resulting array into comma-separated arguments, then do something really **really evil** and use `eval`:

```
$args_imploded = implode(',', $some_array);

$result = eval('return array_intersect(' . $args_imploded . ')');
```

Comment: Oh so `eval` is the trick. Understood. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just avoid the evil eval function and use the '[call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)' function? From what I understand about your code is that the $final_array parameter is an array of array's.

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $final_array);
```

No need for the eval function here.

**EDIT: Stupid me. I didn't read your first paragraph properly ;). Please ignore this.**

Comment: No problem :) It was just a matter of curiosity :) but thanks anyways... +1 for the solution.